# A program that reads input until end-of-file and echoes it to the display

Tags: beginner, c, io

It echoes files or strings to output, never both at once. It does work (in both Linux and Windows), but I can NOT guarantee that it is bug free. It works much like echo, but it works with files as well, and has fewer formal arguments.

I'm looking for helpful and useful critiques, mainly in programming style, organization, and if it's easily understood (or if there was difficulty in understanding) source code. If any critiques are made, please add in how I can improve upon my "misdeeds".

```
//Problem 11-15
/*
*************************************************************
CHP 11 Problem #15
*************************************************************
Write a program that reads input until end-of-file and echoes 
it to the display. Have the program recognize and implement 
the following command-line arguments:
*************************************************************
-p -- Print input as is
-u -- Map input to all uppercase
-l -- Map input to all lowercase
*************************************************************
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define TITLE "Chapter 11 Exercise 13"
_Bool true = 1, false = 0;
void display(char * string, char arg)
{ //display the string in stdout "as is"
    int col = 0;
    //go character by character to avoid bugs
    //while not null char '\0' or End-of-FILE
    if (arg == 'p')
        while (string[col] && string[col] != EOF)
            putchar(string[col++]);
    if (arg == 'u')
        while (string[col] && string[col] != EOF)
            putchar(toupper(string[col++]));        
    if (arg == 'l')
        while (string[col] && string[col] != EOF)
            putchar(tolower(string[col++]));
    putchar('\n'); //formatted padding
}
void pfile(char * fname, char arg)
{ //print the files contents to stdout "as is"
    FILE * fp;
    char ch;
    fp = fopen(fname, "r"); //open file for reading
    if(fp == NULL) //attempt failed
    {
        printf("Oops! Something went wrong while attempting to open the file.\n");
        puts("The file may be missing, corrupted, or may not exist.");
        exit(1); //quit program
    }
    //getc(fp) gets a character from the open file
    if (arg == 'p')
        while((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF)
            putchar(ch);
    if (arg == 'u')
        while((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF)
            putchar(toupper(ch));
    if (arg == 'l')
        while((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF)
            putchar(tolower(ch));
    fclose(fp); //close the file
}
int fext(char * string)
{//determine if there is a file extension
    //flag which value to return
    int i, ch, scan, place, flag = false;
    //while string is not a null character,
    //assign flag a boolean value,
    //break while if a character matches
    for (i = 0; string[i]; i++)
    {
        if (string[i] == '.')
        {
            //check if next char is a space char
            if (isspace(string[i + 1])) break;
            //count characters after '.'
            for (scan = i, place = 0; string[i+scan]; scan++) ++place;
            scan = i + 1; //advance by one character
            //only ASCII or Plain Text files are allowed
            if (!strncmp(string+scan,"txt",place))
            {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
            if (!strncmp(string+scan,"asc",place))
            {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
            if (!strncmp(string+scan,"c",place))
            {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
            if (!strncmp(string+scan,"csv",place))
            {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
            if (!strncmp(string+scan,"html",place))
            {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
            if (!strncmp(string+scan,"log",place))
            {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
            if (!strncmp(string+scan,"xhtml",place))
            {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
            if (!strncmp(string+scan,"xml",place))
            {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return flag; //assume *string is a string literal
}
int option(char * string)
{//determine if string is a formal argument
    auto int i, place, arg = false;
    if (string[0] == '-' && string[1] == '-' && isalpha(string[2]))
    {
        for (i = 0; string[i]; i++) //count alpha based chars
            if (isalpha(string[i])) 
                ++place;
        if (!strncmp((string + 2),"help",place))
        {
            arg = 'h'; //return the help argument
        }
        if (!strncmp((string + 2),"print",place))
        {
            arg = 'p'; //return the argument to print as is
        }
        if (!strncmp((string + 2),"uppercase",place))
        {
            arg = 'u'; //return the uppercase argument
        }
        if (!strncmp((string + 2),"lowercase",place))
        {
            arg = 'l'; //return the lowercase argument
        }
    }
    else if (string[0] == '-' && isalpha(string[1]))
    {
        switch (string[1])
        {
            case 'h':
                arg = 'h';
                break;
            case 'p':
                arg = 'p';
                break;
            case 'u':
                arg = 'u';
                break;
            case 'l':
                arg = 'l';
                break;
            default:
                arg = false;
                break;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        arg = false;
    }
    return arg; //assume *string is a string literal
}
void help(char * string)
{
    printf("Usage: %s [OPTION]... [FILE] or [STRING]...\n", string);
    puts("Echoes FILE or STRING until End-of-FILE to the display.\n");
    printf("%s%50s\n", "-h, --help", "Prints this help text to the display.");
    printf("%s%49s\n", "-p, --print", "Prints the FILE as is to the display.");
    printf("%s%40s\n", "-u, --uppercase", "Maps the input to all uppercase.");
    printf("%s%40s\n", "-l, --lowercase", "Maps the input to all lowercase.");
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ //main program
    //extension, option
    auto int ext, opt; 
    switch(argc)
    {
        case 2:
            //check to see if input is an argument
            if ((opt = option(argv[1])) == 'h') //if argument is for help
            {
                help(argv[0]); //print only the help text to the display
                break;
            }
            if (opt) //if only an optional argument is made
            {
                printf("%s: missing FILE or STRING operand\n", argv[0]);
                printf("Try '%s --help' for more information.\n", argv[0]);
                break;
            }
            //check to see if input is string or file
            if (!opt && (ext = fext(argv[1]))) //if a file was provided with no opt
                pfile(argv[1], 'p'); //print FILE as is -- default argument
            else if (!opt && !ext)  //if no opt or file was provided
                display(argv[1], 'p'); //print STRING as is -- default argument
            break;
        case 3:
            if ((opt = option(argv[1])) == 'h')
            {
                help(argv[0]);
                break;
            }
            else if (opt)
                ext = fext(argv[2]);
            else
            {
                opt = false;
                ext = false;
            }
            if (opt && ext) //if option and file extension are valid and present
                pfile(argv[2], opt);
            else if (opt && !ext) //if option is present, but file is missing
                display(argv[2], opt);
            else
            {
                printf("%s: invalid OPTION was provided\n", argv[0]);
                printf("Try '%s --help' for more information.\n", argv[0]);
            }
            break;
        default:
            printf("%s: invalid arguments were made\n", argv[0]);
            printf("Try '%s --help' for more information.\n", argv[0]);
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Having a program that sometimes acts as `echo` and sometimes acts as `cat` (or `type`, if you use Windows) depending on the presence of a known file extension in the string argument is, frankly, weird.  I don't think that it fulfills the requirements of the stated exercise or has a good use case, but I'll play along.

I agree with @Brythan that the code could benefit greatly from having a blank line or two between functions.

The outline of the code is quite good — I like the way you split up the work into this set of functions.  There is a lot that can be simplified within each function, though.  I'll start reviewing from the top.

### `display()`

You should generally avoid doing I/O one character at a time, as each call to `putchar()` can have a relatively large overhead for a system call.  A single call to `puts()` would be better.

The code is essentially repeated three times, with variants for passthrough, uppercase, and lowercase.  A good way to avoid such repetition is to specify a transformation, which is passed in as a function pointer.  First, we define a `passthrough()` function that is analogous to `toupper()` and `tolower()`:

```
int passthrough(int c) {
    return c;
}
```

Then, the `display()` function could be written like this:

```
void display(char *string, int (*transform)(int))
{
    for (char *s = string; *s; s++)
    {
        *s = transform(*s);
    }
    puts(string);
}
```

See the discussion of `main()` below to see how `display()` is called.

### `pfile()`

`print_file()` would be a clearer name.

As with `display()`, I recommend using a transformation function and avoiding `putchar()`.

The error handling could be better.  Errors should be printed to `stderr`, to avoid contaminating `stdout`.  Instead of "something went wrong", you could tell the user exactly what failed.  (By the way file corruption won't cause `fopen()` to fail.  Filesystem corruption could cause it to fail.  Other failure modes are also possible, such as lack of permission.)  I suggest returning -1 on error, and having the caller use `perror()` to print the diagnostics.  Having `exit()` calls sprinkled in various places around your code makes the function less reusable and your program harder to maintain.

Comments such as `exit(1); //quit program` and `fclose(fp); //close the file` are pointless.  I recommend omitting them.  Put more effort into documenting the function's purpose, parameters, and return values instead.

```
/**
 * Prints the contents of the file, after applying a transformation, to stdout.
 * Returns the number of bytes printed, if successful, or -1 on error.
 */
int print_file(const char *filename, int (*transform)(int))
{
    size_t size, total = 0;
    char buffer[8192];
    FILE *fp;
    if (NULL == (fp = fopen(filename, "r")))
    {
        return -1;
    }
    while ((size = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), fp)))
    {
        total += size;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            buffer[i] = transform(buffer[i]);
        }
        fwrite(buffer, 1, size, stdout);
    }
    int retval = feof(fp) ? total : -1;
    fclose(fp);
    return retval;
}
```

### `fext()`

The function should have a better name.  It could also be written in a much simpler way.

```
int known_file_extension(const char *filename)
{
    char *dotext;
    if ((dotext = strrchr(filename, '.')))
    {
        return 0 == strcmp(dotext, ".txt") ||
               0 == strcmp(dotext, ".asc") ||
               0 == strcmp(dotext, ".c") ||
               0 == strcmp(dotext, ".csv") ||
               0 == strcmp(dotext, ".html") ||
               0 == strcmp(dotext, ".log") ||
               0 == strcmp(dotext, ".xhtml") ||
               0 == strcmp(dotext, ".xml");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### `option()`

For proper treatment of command-line options, `getopt()` is the way to go.  However, I can understand that `getopt()` is a bit complicated, and your own code could be easier to follow.

I prefer to think of `option()` as returning a `char`, possibly the `'-'` character if the option is not recognized, or the NUL character if it doesn't look like an option at all.

Here's a simpler implementation.

```
/**
 * Returns 'h', 'p', 'u', or 'l' if the string contains the help, print,
 * upperase, or lowercase option, respectively.  Returns '-' if the string
 * contains an unrecognized option.  Returns '\0' if string is not an
 * option that starts with a hyphen.
 */
char option(const char *string)
{
    if (string[0] == '-' && string[1] == '-')
    {
        if (0 == strcmp(string + 2, "help"))      return 'h';
        if (0 == strcmp(string + 2, "print"))     return 'p';
        if (0 == strcmp(string + 2, "uppercase")) return 'u';
        if (0 == strcmp(string + 2, "lowercase")) return 'l';
        return '-';
    }
    else if (string[0] == '-' && string[1] != '\0' && string[2] == '\0')
    {
        switch (string[1])
        {
          case 'h':
          case 'p':
          case 'u':
          case 'l':
            return string[1];
        }
        return '-';
    }
    return '\0';
}
```

### `help()`

Generally, help functions need to print to `stdout` if the help was explicitly requested, or to `stderr` if the program was called with unreasonable parameters.

I suggest printing just the basename of the program (stripping out the directory, if any).

For formatting, don't hard-code weird column widths while right-aligning the second column.  Instead, specify a fixed width on the first column.

In the text, "until End-of-File" is confusingly placed after "STRING".

```
void help(FILE *out, char *argv0)
{
    fprintf(out, "Usage: %s [OPTION]... [STRING] or [FILE]...\n"
                 "Echoes STRING or FILE until End-of-FILE to the display.\n\n",
                 basename(argv0));
    fprintf(out, "%-23s%s\n", "-h, --help",
                              "Prints this help text to the display.");
    fprintf(out, "%-23s%s\n", "-p, --print",
                              "Prints the FILE as is to the display.");
    fprintf(out, "%-23s%s\n", "-u, --uppercase",
                              "Maps the input to all uppercase.");
    fprintf(out, "%-23s%s\n", "-l, --lowercase",
                              "Maps the input to all lowercase.");
}
```

### `main()`

The logic would be simpler if you didn't treat the two-argument and three-argument cases separately.

If the parameters are invalid, you might as well show the help message instead of telling the user to run the program with the `--help` option.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int (*transform)(int) = passthrough;    // passthrough, toupper, or tolower
    char *string = NULL;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        switch (option(argv[i]))
        {
          case '-':
            help(stderr, argv[0]);
            return 1;
          case 'h':
            help(stdout, argv[0]);
            return 0;
          case 'p':
            transform = passthrough;
            break;
          case 'u':
            transform = toupper;
            break;
          case 'l':
            transform = tolower;
            break;
          default:
            string = argv[i];
        }
    }
    if (!string)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: missing FILE or STRING operand\n", basename(argv[0]));
        help(stderr, argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (known_file_extension(string))
    {
        if (-1 == print_file(string, transform))
        {
            perror(string);
            return 2;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        display(string, transform);
    }
}
```

Comment: For your `known_file_extension()` method, the OP could also consider storing the extensions in an array and then looping over them.  Shortens the code down a bit, and is more maintainable IMO.

Comment: i'm not sure that i understand what is going on with the modified version of display, display(int *, int (*)(int)). are you saying that transform is a pointer-to-pointer-of-ints (or, in other words, a multidimensional array)? When i read int (*transform)(int), im thinking multi or compound literal. i mainly used int because chars were one byte, bools 2 bytes usually, and if i needed to pass a signed value that int would allow me to do that.

Comment: No, `transform` is a pointer to a function that accepts an `int` and returns an `int`. It's a way for the caller to tell `display()` to call a chunk of code to perform the transformation.

Comment: you just taught me something new and very cool. i had no idea that i could create function calls like that. i still consider myself very new to programming and C was my first choice. i guess you could say i just dove in the deep end of it all (and im still learning and reviewing, gotta get into structures again soon). as i wrote the program, i could tell there were better ways to do what i was attempting to do, i just didn't know how and since i'm teaching myself, i thought some peer review might lift my spirits and give me some good feedback. which so far, i'm very impressed.

Comment: [Chat session](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/conversation/using-function-pointers-in-c) explaining function pointers

Answer (score 9):

```
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define TITLE "Chapter 11 Exercise 13"
_Bool true = 1, false = 0;
void display(char * string, char arg)
```

I would find this easier to read with more vertical spacing.

```
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define TITLE "Chapter 11 Exercise 13"

_Bool true = 1, false = 0;

void display(char * string, char arg)
```

Now I can quickly see where the comment section ends and the include section begins.  Then there's a define section; a definition; and finally the code begins.

```
if(fp == NULL) //attempt failed
{
```

I would avoid putting comments between a control statement and its statement or block.  Actually, I avoid putting comments to the right of code in general.  I'd prefer

```
//attempt failed
if ( NULL == fp )
{
```

or

```
if ( NULL == fp )
{
    //attempt failed
```

I also flipped the equality check.  Done this way, `NULL = fp` will throw a compiler error.  The other way, that typo will sort of silently do the wrong thing and lead to a run-time error later in the code.

```
    exit(1); //quit program
```

Try to avoid comments that just say what the code does.  Your code should generally be readable enough that comments that explain what are unnecessary.  The time to use comments is to explain why.

Also, I'd have written this as

```
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

This is clearer about why you are returning that value.  You are already including `stdlib.h`, so you have `EXIT_FAILURE` and `EXIT_SUCCESS` available.

```
for (i = 0; string[i]; i++)
{
    if (string[i] == '.')
    {
```

You can do this if you want.  I personally would prefer

```
while ( NULL != string )
{
    if ( '.' == *(string++) )
    {
```

That would leave the string pointing after the period.

Even better:

```
char *extension;
extension = strrchr( string, '.' );
if ( NULL == extension ) {
    return false;
}
```

That creates a pointer to the string after the period.

```
        if (isspace(string[i + 1])) break;
```

This seems unnecessary.  Spaces are valid characters in filenames.  Seldom used and problematic but valid.  There's nothing in your original program that would be thrown off by a space.

```
        for (scan = i, place = 0; string[i+scan]; scan++) ++place;
```

Then I'd replace that line with

```
    place = strlen(extension);
```

After that, do

```
switch ( place ) 
{
    case 6:
        if ( 0 == strcmp(extension, "xhtml")
        {
            return true;
        }
        break;
```

Add the other extension lengths as necessary.  Note that there is no point in using `strncmp` here as your original code relies on the string being null terminated.  If `strcmp` were problematic, you'd have already hit that problem.  Your original code would also have matched *file.xht* with the *xhtml* extension which seems unlikely to be what you want.

I also removed your `flag` variable.  It's unnecessary since you can just return directly.  Some people prefer to have only one return at the end of a statement, but if you're going to do that, you should generally avoid other flow control statements, like `break`.  So you'd change your later `if` statements to `else if` and add a `! flag` check to your outer loop.  E.g.

```
for (i = 0; string[i] && ! flag; i++)
```

But all this is unnecessary.  You check the file extension and use the result to determine if the file is a text file.  This can go wrong either way.  The file **README** is almost always a text file, but your program would refuse to read it.  If I save an image or other binary with a *.txt* extension, your program will accept it.  There's a Unix command called `file` which analyzes the contents of a file.  You could use a system call to get the results of that or presumably access a library somewhere that does the same thing.

If you use a system call, be careful to quote it properly.  This is where a space (or worse, a semicolon) could be problematic.  Test with at least `"test.txt'; echo 'Oops' '"` as an argument.

```
auto int i, place, arg = false;
```

You never have to use the `auto` keyword in C.  All variables are declared `auto` by default (unless explicitly declared `static` or `extern`).  If you have some weird corner case where this matters, you should comment here.

```
if (string[0] == '-' && string[1] == '-' && isalpha(string[2]))
{
    for (i = 0; string[i]; i++) //count alpha based chars
        if (isalpha(string[i])) 
            ++place;
    if (!strncmp((string + 2),"help",place))
```

Again, I think `place` is unnecessary.  Note that if there is one or more non-alpha characters at the end of the string, that this will match if the rest matches.  Unless you want that behavior, you can skip the place calculation.  Also, it's unclear why you keep going if you encounter a non-alpha character.  You could just return at that point, since the string will never match.

You might want to look into how [Getopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html) works.  That could help save you writing your own scaffolding in cases like this.

```
        if (!opt && (ext = fext(argv[1]))) //if a file was provided with no opt
```

Rather than checking the extension, why not [check if the file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/230062/2625983)?  If it does, then you can print the file if it is text based.  If not, then you can print the entry as a string.

```
return 0;
```

You don't need to `return 0` at the end of `main`.  If you let it fall through, the compiler will add this for you.

Comment: `//` comments are part of the C99 standard. For new code being written in 2014 (almost 2015!), I think it's fair to use.

Comment: you made some great points. i'll add more spacing in my code, but not too much, in the future. i had completely forgotten about the EXIT_FAILURE macro even though i had thrown in the exit() function in there for that purpose. strrchr( string, '.' ) is cleaner and requires less code on my part, same with strlen(). i should have done that, i was just so caught up in making the program do what i wanted.

Comment: as for GetOpt. that's very advanced for me right now seeing that my experience with either Linux or Windows CLI is very limited and elementary. i barely know how to use GCC and GDB. i'm mainly focused on grasping the concepts within the modern C language itself. as interesting as it is, because i did end up reading some of the documentation (a lot of it actually), GNU isn't the easiest documentation to read (it takes some time getting use to the density of all its documentation), but it does always get its message across. GNU docs have saved me many times.